# Magento 2: Undefined Index Error When Upgrading to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3

When upgrading to magento 2.3.3 I get the following error.

- I have already ran `composer install`
- Error occurs when running: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

> Notice: Undefined index: search_query in /home/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php on line 352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be because `Magento_Search` is turned off. You can get passed this error by enabling the module.
in `app/etc/config.php`
change the line

```php
'Magento_Search' => 0,
```

to

```
'Magento_Search' => 1,
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but that was not in my env.php file. I added it but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @MattCosentino sorry I made a typo, check your app/etc/config.php